# Getting NullPointerException and FacesContext not found error in f:view tag

Tags: jsf

I am trying to run a very simple hello world example JSF program in my server.
But I am getting this error and `NullPointerException` error at `<f:view>` itself.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /main_page_view.jsp at line 9

6: String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
7: %>
8: 
9: <f:view>
10: <html>
11:   <head>
12:  


Stacktrace:       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:524)     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:435)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

root cause 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext
javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.getFacesContext(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1797)
javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:161    4)
org.apache.jsp.main_005fpage_005fview_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(main_005fpage_005fview_jsp.java:90)
org.apache.jsp.main_005fpage_005fview_jsp._jspService(main_005fpage_005fview_jsp.java:67)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

I have below faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
              version="1.2">

</faces-config>
```

Also in my web.xml,I have below things.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Below is my main_page_view.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath =   request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>

<f:view>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>My JSP 'main_page_view.jsp' starting page</title>

            <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
            <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
            <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
            <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3">
            <meta http-equiv="description" content="This is my page">
            <!--
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
            -->
        </head>
        <body>
            <br>This is my JSP page. <br>
        </body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

I have not added anything thing extra in my project not even the jars.
I am using the MyEclipse editor and during the project creation it has given my below jars     by its own.

- javaee.jar
- jsf-impl.jar
- jsf-api.jar
- jstl-1.2.jar

Can anyone please help on this, and please give me any working solution. I am not getting   any clue. I have also tried putting jars in the lib folder and then started getting the `NullPointerException` on the `<f:view>` tags.

Comment: I have edited the exception, please take a look in that. Also, 
as per the above the comment "By the way, try finding a JSF 2.x tutorial. JSF 1.x is dead for long and JSP has been deprecated",

 Do i need to use the XHTML instead of using jsp,

Comment: Thanks. I got the solution. Now it is working for me, 
I simply called main_page_view.jsf instead of main_page_view.jsp
also added the below servlet mapping and changed <welcome-file> type from index.jsp to index.jsf to initialize the faces context as given below.   
 
   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
  
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>